# How to use ftp_put with utf-8 characters

Tags: php, utf-8, ftp

I am using a custom function that creates a text file with fopen() and then this text file is uploaded on a server using ftp_put in ASCII mode.

My problem is that once the file is uploaded and once I open it in my text editor, accents are automatically transformed into gibberish characters instead of staying the same.

I know there is no FTP transfer mode for UTF-8, so what php function should I use to keep the utf-8 characters properly formatted once I open the file that has been uploaded?

```
fopen(..., 'w+')
original string : é
ftp_put(...., FTP_ASCII)
once the file is uploaded, the string looks like: Ã©n
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use FTP_ASCII. This mode automatically converts the line endings from the platform standard of the FTP client into the platform standard of the FTP server. Always use binary mode - this will transfer all files unchanged.

And then: How do you check the file was uploaded correctly, and how are you actually transferring the data?

Comment: No luck with FTP_BINARY, I use ftp_fget(...FTP_BINARY, 0) to grab the file, then write some content in it with fputcsv, and then use ftp_put(..., FTP_BINARY)

Comment: Doesn't answer my question. Note that details are very important. Getting one bit wrong, or some bytes, is basically the reason for your problem, but it can only be analyzed if you don't skip over the important details of what you are actually doing, and just blame FTP. I think FTP is not the problem here, it is "write some content" into the downloaded file. Check the content has the correct encoding. Print out the very bytes the content is made of (use `urlencode()` for an easy byte-dump output).